# Qt rand() doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, random, numbers

I want to show 1000 random numbers from 0 to 99 999. But there is a kinda weird problem with that. It shows 1000 numbers but none of them is higher than aprox. 35 000. Why is that?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    int ran;

    qsrand(qrand());

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        ran = qrand() % 100000;
        qInfo() << ran;
    }    

    return a.exec();
}
```

What console showed me is:

> 18103
>   76
>   22033
>   25191
>   5349
>   13724
>   11988
>   25919
>   32568
>   20303
>   17393
>   14983
>   4038
>   443
>   16566
>   18275
>   8687
>   23110
>   24124
>   31899
>   20267
>   2336
>   22086
>   3570
>   6406
>   29490
>   32107
>   13236
>   29800
>   8273
>   18552
>   10895
>   6682
>   22968
>   16656
>   26019
>   16518
>   3253
>   11669
>   9948
>   8894
>   17826
>   28748
>   29056
>   30912
>   22295
>   25019
>   2820
>   17657
>   350
>   10838
>   32292
>   6919
>   11815
>   24411
>   21555
>   17347
>   5245
>   26363
>   30895
>   25215
>   22777
>   26554
>   31512
>   32652
>   32310
>   18200
>   8962
>   7168
>   14724
>   31601
>   2666
>   12981
>   32737
>   13602
>   12870
>   19093
>   24357
>   8941
>   17759
>   32277
>   30588
>   21919
>   32099
>   7168
>   10521
>   1775
>   24118
>   17782
>   18985
>   18346
>   15242
>   11572
>   30982
>   22797
>   15535
>   23574
>   24238
>   13682
>   21164
>   7897
>   30067
>   3120
>   21646
>   294
>   10228
>   13500
>   13824
>   31180
>   23627
>   23828
>   3100
>   11342
>   16264
>   30557
>   21633
>   25501
>   25951
>   10954
>   12966
>   10790
>   4125
>   19393
>   5998
>   8975
>   13536
>   7993
>   1788
>   2238
>   4104
>   28007
>   28872
>   29852
>   24041
>   10137
>   19954
>   21528
>   3010
>   9570
>   31191
>   12014
>   29939
>   15607
>   30947
>   8873
>   106
>   15065
>   8614
>   14182
>   12895
>   31924
>   23593
>   29148
>   1601
>   13191
>   27522
>   18073
>   9456
>   4358
>   30118
>   21134
>   19244
>   25661
>   15743
>   31950
>   29774
>   26997
>   17214
>   26003
>   7477
>   20827
>   16115
>   18050
>   13188
>   17247
>   10586
>   10288
>   1291
>   24411
>   18168
>   4324
>   17282
>   629
>   26983
>   4255
>   28797
>   21318
>   23279
>   20057
>   17820
>   22844
>   10326
>   31374
>   27906
>   9020
>   15608
>   19193
>   7689
>   16780
>   1306
>   25504
>   29236
>   5873
>   2683
>   20752
>   1638
>   17684
>   16172
>   30698
>   15441
>   14378
>   27298
>   7582
>   12336
>   5588
>   27914
>   28279
>   14009
>   4932
>   19676

See? None of these numbers are higher than 35000. What did I wrong?

Comment: output on my machine looks OK (e.g 74537, 9993, 54396 appear there).

Comment: 2^15 is "about 35000". It looks like you're working with a signed 16-bit integer.

Comment: So how can I change this? for ex on 32-bit integer?

Comment: `qrand()` function returns a value between 0 and RAND_MAX (defined in <cstdlib> and <stdlib.h>). RAND_MAX const is compiler-dependent, so better to use new random functions from C++11

Comment: @ramzes2 I used normal rand() function and srand(time(NULL)) instead but it did not work. The result is the same.

Comment: I mean these new functions http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Issue

Actually it is 32767. The behavior in this case is identical to the standard [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/):

> Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.

And the similar statement in the [`qrand()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qrand) docs:

> Returns a value between 0 and `RAND_MAX` (defined in `<cstdlib>` and `<stdlib.h>`).

Obviously the `RAND_MAX` in your case is equal to 32767 (2¹⁵ – 1).

#### Solution

The solution is to use C++11 random number generators:

```
#include <random>

// ...

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
const int min = 0;
const int max = 99999;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> ds(min, max);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    qDebug() << ds(mt);
}
```

Comment: Yes I agree with you. That was a problem. After application these new random function from c++11 everything works fine. Thank you!